# Variable sent through POST Method brings lots of blank spaces PHP

Tags: php

Thanks everyone adding the name to the select tag did the trick.

but now the value that is sent trough the post method is something like this

```
$_document =                   Andres
```

with lots of blank spaces and i wish to obtain something clean like

```
$_document=Andres
```

Any ideas?

I'm having troubles with a variable that needs to be sent through POST method. Heres the code:

```
 <td>
   <label>Nombre</label><input type="text" id="_name" name="_name" value="<?=$_name?>" class="name" />
   <label>URL</label><input type="text" id="_permalink" name="_permalink" value="<?=$_permalink?>" class="name" />
   <label>Fecha</label><input type="text" id="_date" name="_date" value="<?=date_to_javascript_short($_date)?>" />
   <input type="checkbox" id="_featured" value="s" name="_featured" class="checkbox" <?= $_featured == "s" ? "checked='checked'" : "" ?> /><label for="_featured" class="checkbox">Marcar como relevante</label>

  <label>Carpeta</label>

  **<select>
      <?  $document = process_all("SELECT _document_name FROM _document WHERE _owner = 'Marco Regulatorio' ORDER BY _document_name ");
      if($document) {
       foreach ($document as $item) {
         echo "<option id='_document' value=' ";?>
         <?=$_document=$item[_document_name]?>
         <?echo "'>";
         echo "$item[_document_name] </option>";        
        }
      }
        ?>
      </select>**
   </td>
```

The `$_name`, `$_permalink` and other variables are sent correctly using the post method the one that gives the problem is the one in the select tag, the `$_document` variable, first to explain is that I get the content for the options tag using a DB, then I set the options that will show using PHP for it but I really don't get why wont it send the $_document variable using the post method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select doesn't have a name to be sent as.

Just add a name attribute to the select tag and try.

Answer (score 1):

Give the select tag the name "_document" the way you named the input "_name".

Comment: By the way, you should not give all options the same value for the id property. The id should be unique throughout the HTML document.